# $(event.target).attr('data-action') return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some button function to show some data when clicked in this table.

```html
    <tbody>
        <tr id="trid">
            <td><i class="fas fa-plus-circle" data-action="onExpand"></i></td>
            <td>number</td>
            <td>component</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

But, when I clicked on the button with `data-action` attribute, it will return undefined or the object is not a function.

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if(typeof options != 'undefined'){
            options.language = {emptyTable :"there is no data on this table"};
        }
        var table = $(dataTableElement).DataTable(options);
        $(dataTableElement).on('click', '[data-action]', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
    
            var target = $(e.target);
    
            if (target.children().length == 0) target = $(e.target).parent();
               
            var action = target.attr('data-action'); //<---- the problem in here
    
            var tr = target.closest('tr');
            var row = table.row(tr);
            var data = row.data();
    
            if (typeof window[action] === 'function') {
                window[action](data, row, tr); //<----- object is not a function on here
            } else {
                console.log('function ' + action + ' not found ');
            }
        });
    });
```

Can anyone give me some advice please ? because I don't know how to fix this.
thank you

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: So when you click on the `<i>` then you get the variable `target`, then just below, you ask if `target / i` has no children, if so then you set target to be the `td`. I think that is the problem because the `td` does not have the attribute `data-action`

Comment: Aka I dont understand why you want `if (target.children().length == 0) target = $(e.target).parent();`

Comment: Your <i> doesnt have a child m8. Thats your problem! Therefore if you want the Action, execute the var action before the if target.children().length === 0... What do you expect if you change the target before you read the data out? Yikers :)

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen god damn I just remove that `if (target.children().length == 0) target = $(e.target).parent();`, and it worked, this is so akward, thank you very much